# How to insert data from csv to access db if the column names and order is different

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, ms-access, csv

It is using c# programming.
I am selecting the csv file and inserting it in to the access db. I have say, 6 columns in the csv file like ID, FName, LName, Address, Zipcode, cell number in the same order. In access, my columns are FirstName, LastName, S_NO, zip_code (in the same order). How i can import this csv file in to access db, if the column names are different as well the order is different. How can i implement this?? Pls suggest.
I tried the following code:

```
enter code here
```

DataSet da = new DataSet();
            try
            {

```
            da = this.ConnectCSV(strCSVFile);
            string connstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\EmpApp\\EmpData.accdb;";
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connstring);
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            conn.Open();
            for (int i = 0; i <= da.Tables["Ss"].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {

                for (int j = 1; j <= da.Tables["Ss"].Columns.Count - 1; j++)
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "Insert  into EMP_DOWNLOAD ( ID,Company_name,month_billed,year,start_date,end_date,Designation"
                      + ")  values(" + (i + 1) + ",'" 
                      + da.Tables["Ss"].Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(0) + "',"
                      + da.Tables["Ss"].Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(8) + 
                      da.Tables["Ss"].Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(9) + ")";                        
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                 }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            btnUpload.Enabled = false;
        }
enter code here
```

Comment: Hi nikky, you have already run into problems with this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197759/insert-data-from-dataset-in-to-access-db. It is best to include some code with a code question.

Comment: Thanks Remou. Added the code i tried to import to access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With MS Access, you can run straight from CSV to a table:

```
INSERT INTO EMP_DOWNLOAD (ID, Forename, LastName, Address, Zip_Code ) 
SELECT  ID, FName, LName, Address, Zipcode
FROM [Text;Database=z:\docs\;HDR=yes].[importfilename.csv]
```

Comment: Yes. But in the csv file, my column names and order is different than the access file column names and order. That is the issue.

Comment: No it is not. Just list the names in the same order in the insert and select as shown above. It does not matter which order they are in in the table or csv.

Comment: But the primary key should be same for both csv and access file?

Comment: You are trying to run an update rather than an append, is that correct?

Comment: If you have an autonumber ID and wish to append, just do not include ID as a field on either side.

Comment: cmd.CommandText = "Insert into EMP_DOWNLOAD ( ID,emp_name,bill_month) SELECT (ID, employeename, monthlybill) FROM [Text,Data Source=C:\\EmpDownload\\EmpData.accdb;HDR=YES].[strCSVFile]";                 While running i am getting "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '(ID,employeename,bill_month)'.

Comment: Correct the errors `[Text,Data Source` should be `[Text;Data Source` and strCSVFile should be a file name and `Data Source=C:\\EmpDownload\\EmpData.accdb` should be the directory / folder where the text file is located. You should be running against a connection to the Access database.

Comment: I don't have any text file here. all i have is .csv file and access file at different locations. :(

Comment: A csv file is a text file. It has a folder, does it not?

Comment: cmd.CommandText = "Insert into EMP_DOWNLOAD (ID,emp_name,month_bill) values SELECT (ID,employee name,month_billed) FROM [Text;Database=C:\\EmpDownload;HDR=YES].[filename]";

Comment: Like so: `Insert into EMP_DOWNLOAD (ID,emp_name,month_bill)  SELECT ID,[employee name],month_billed FROM [Text;Database=C:\EmpDownload\;HDR=YES].[filename.csv]`

Answer (score 1):

I would use a Linq statement to break your text apart and create arrays of your parameter objects then loop through the arrays adding the parameters to each insert statement that is sent to the database.

Like this

```
var csvParams = (from line in System.IO.File.ReadLines("fileName.csv")
            from cell in line.Split(',').AsEnumerable()
            select new[]
            {
                new OleDbParameter("@fn", cell[1]),
                new OleDbParameter("@ln", cell[2]),
                new OleDbParameter("@sn", cell[3]),
                new OleDbParameter("@zc", cell[4])
            });

using( OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("CONNECTION STRING GOES HERE"))
{
    foreach (var person in csvParams)
    {
        using (OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO People(FirstName, LastName, S_NO, zip_code) VALUES (@fn, @ln, @sn, @zc)";
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange( (OleDbParameter[]) person);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: But, my values are not static. The values are coming from .csv file with column names and order is different than access file.

Comment: Let me see if I understand you. Do you mean that the order or the column names in the csv can change from csv to csv or is the order of the columns in the csv just different than the access database but consistent through all csv's. If it's the later then my solution should work you just have to ensure that the values stored in the OleDbParameter has a short name (ex: @fn) that corresponds to the one in the query. The order of the OleDbParameters passed into the AddRange method is of no consequence. If it is the former then it will require a little more thought and involve a lookup table.

Comment: Let me clarify that. I have firstname,Lastname,empid as columns in csv file and in access, i have fname,lname,e_id as columns. Now, i want to insert csv file data in to access. But, column names are different. How can i do that??

Comment: As long as the column order doesn't change from CSV to CSV then my solution should work. All you need to do is correlate the array locations that are passed to the OleDBParameter to the short name that is passed into the query. The array location corresponds to the column in the csv file.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass null for the filed which are not required..