# is It correct Sql to import data from csv file into msaccess

Tags: sql, csv, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

```
"INSERT INTO CricketMatch
(FName,LastName,Runs,Matches,Location,DateofMatch,PLayerId)
SELECT
    Fname,Lname,Runsby,numberofMatches,MatchLocation,DofMatch,Id
FROM [Text;Data Source=C:\\DB\\;HDR=YES].[filename]";
```

filename is just name with extension demo.csv no path

```
cmd.CDataSet da = new DataSet();string filename = Path.GetFileName(txtCSVFilePath.Text);
try {da = this.ConnectCSV(filename);
     string connstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\DB\\MatchDetails.accdb"; 
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connstring);
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;conn.Open(); 
    for (int i = 0; i <= da.Tables["Ss"].Rows.Count - 1; i++){ 
        for (int j = 1; j <= da.Tables["Ss"].Columns.Count - 1;j++){ 
           cmd.CommandText="INSERTINTOCricketMatch(FName,LastName,Runs,Matches,Location,DateofMatch,PLayerId)SELECT(Fname,Lname,Runsby,numberofMatches,MatchLocation,DofMatch,Id)  FROM [Text;FMT=Delimited(;);HDR=NO;DATABASE=C:\\DB]." + filename;cmd.Connection = conn; cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();} }}
```

this is what i am trying

Comment: have you tried it or not??

Comment: Syntax error (comma) in query expression '(Fname,Lname,Runsby,numberofMatches,MatchLocation,DofMatch,Id)'. this is the exception i am getting ,but there is no ,  @squillman

Comment: This is a copy of an answer I already posted, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218539/how-to-insert-data-from-csv-to-access-db-if-the-column-names-and-order-is-differ/14219209#comment19800336_14219209

Answer (score 4):

Your syntax looks pretty close -- try something like this to connect to the csv file:

```
SELECT Fname,
  Lname,
  Runsby,
  numberofMatches,
  MatchLocation,
  DofMatch,
  Id 
FROM [Text;FMT=Delimited;HDR=YES;DATABASE=C:\DB].filename.csv;
```

Comment: Nope this time it reading all the cell name and giving error as The INSERT INTO statement contains the following unknown field name: 'F1'.  Make sure you have typed the name correctly, and try the operation again. @user1073631

Comment: Okay, that will probably run.

Comment: Does the same method works for excel file too in place of csv?

Answer (score 1):

Like so, as I already said:

```
INSERT INTO CricketMatch
(FName,LastName,Runs,Matches,Location,DateofMatch,PLayerId)
SELECT
    Fname,Lname,Runsby,numberofMatches,MatchLocation,DofMatch,Id
FROM [Text;Database=z:\docs\;HDR=yes].[importfilename.csv]
```

Comment: Syntax error (comma) in query expression '(Fname,Lname,Runsby,numberofMatches,MatchLocation,DofMatch,Id)'. I am not sure it is giving me this error @Remou

Comment: Also try creating a new table like so: `select  *  INTO CricketMatch2
FROM [Text;Database=z:\docs\;HDR=yes].[imp2.txt]` ideally use the MS Access query design window sql view.

Comment: Change to real values and test: `DATABASE=C:\\DB\\].[demo.csv]` Do you have MS Access?